# CentOS 6 OpenSSL Padding Oracle vuln. (CVE-2016-2107)

Tags: centos, centos6, openssl

I am getting a very bad Overall Rating on ssllabs.com, due to the `OpenSSL Padding Oracle Vulnerability (CVE-2016-2107)`.

This is what I am using at the moment (Production Environment):

- Openssl 1.0.1e
- CentOS 6.5
- Apache 2.2.26 (installed manually; i.e not used yum here)

More details here:

```
yum info openssl

Installed Packages
Name        : openssl
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 1.0.1e
Release     : 57.el6
Size        : 4.1 M
Repo        : installed
From repo   : base
Summary     : A general purpose cryptography library with TLS implementation
URL         : http://www.openssl.org/
License     : OpenSSL
Description : The OpenSSL toolkit provides support for secure communications between
            : machines. OpenSSL includes a certificate management tool and shared
            : libraries which provide various cryptographic algorithms and
            : protocols.

Available Packages
Name        : openssl
Arch        : i686
Version     : 1.0.1e
Release     : 57.el6
Size        : 1.5 M
Repo        : base
Summary     : A general purpose cryptography library with TLS implementation
URL         : http://www.openssl.org/
License     : OpenSSL
Description : The OpenSSL toolkit provides support for secure communications between
            : machines. OpenSSL includes a certificate management tool and shared
            : libraries which provide various cryptographic algorithms and
            : protocols.

rpm -q --changelog "openssl" | head -n 7
* Tue Jan 31 2017 Tomáš Mráz <tmraz@redhat.com> 1.0.1e-57
- fix CVE-2017-3731 - DoS via truncated packets with RC4-MD5 cipher

* Wed Nov 02 2016 Tomáš Mráz <tmraz@redhat.com> 1.0.1e-55
- fix CVE-2016-8610 - DoS of single-threaded servers via excessive alerts

* Sat Oct 22 2016 Tomáš Mráz <tmraz@redhat.com> 1.0.1e-54

ldd mod_ssl.so
ldd: ./mod_ssl.so: No such file or directory

tail -n 200 error_log | grep notice
[Tue Mar 20 14:38:24 2018] [notice] Apache/2.2.26 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.26 OpenSSL/1.0.1h mod_perl/2.0.5 Perl/v5.10.1 configured -- resuming normal operations

rpm -qa |grep openssl
openssl-1.0.1e-57.el6.x86_64
```

How can I solve this issue? I cannot upgrade my CentOS 6.5 now. Also, `yum upgrade openssl` returns nothing.

EDIT:

```
/usr/local/apache2/bin/apachectl -M
Loaded Modules:
 core_module (static)
 authn_file_module (static)
 authn_default_module (static)
 authz_host_module (static)
 authz_groupfile_module (static)
 authz_user_module (static)
 authz_default_module (static)
 auth_basic_module (static)
 include_module (static)
 filter_module (static)
 deflate_module (static)
 log_config_module (static)
 env_module (static)
 expires_module (static)
 headers_module (static)
 setenvif_module (static)
 version_module (static)
 proxy_module (static)
 proxy_connect_module (static)
 proxy_ftp_module (static)
 proxy_ht
```

Comment: RedHat and thus CentOS backports security patches; look further down in the changelog, at -49 in May 2016. You probably have ServerTokens Full (or default) (which the packaged version doesn't) and SSLLabs is looking at the response header, which inaccurately describes the software you are running.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to look if someone has built separate packages of OpenSSL and Apache that can be installed on your system.

However, looking at the OS age, you really should upgrade the whole system, since there are multiple vulnerabilities in that OS.

Comment: I have upgraded the OS on my UAT env; but I still get the same results. After upgrading the OS, when doing a `yum update openssl` I get nothing. So i assume I will need to manually compile and install the openssl 1.1.0 and then re-compile the apache